# Set full width for the inner div

Tags: css, html, width

I have a parent div, Inside that div I have two levels of children div as follow,

```
<div class="grandParant">
    <div class="parant1">test</div> 
    <div class="parant2"> 
        <div class="child">Hello world this is a long test string</div>
         <div class="child">12</div>
         <div class="child">4545</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

from the above sample code, I need to show the entire first "child" class content(Hello world this is a long test string) without any break, ie in a single line.  The width of the "parant2" div should also be incremented with respect to the child width. So how could this be done with css? I am not posting my css since it is a little bit lengthy, but you can see it in jsfiddle.

**EDIT**
my expected output is more like the alphabet 'L'

```
| test |
| Hello world this is a long test string |
| 12                                     |
| 4545                                   |
```

my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/9Sha7/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `max-width` take `parant1` outside of it's grandparent, you'll get your desired result of non-wrapping:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9Sha7/18/**

Comment: no sir, i cant change the with of the grandparent div. Its more like the entire portion should look like the alphabet 'L'. Is there any alterative?

Comment: yes sir, this is what i was expecting for. but you have removed my parant div

Comment: Width of child cannot exceed width of parent? Of course it can, that's what the overflow property is for: http://jsfiddle.net/AftDq/ Another way is [using `position:absolute`](http://jsfiddle.net/AftDq/1/) -- no need for restructuring the HTML.

Comment: @arjuncc If this is the correct answer, please click the tick next to it :). Don't add the solution into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by removing "max-width" ...

Where ever  if you give "max-width" it only get upto that extent only,beyond that width it will break the lines

Put css only like

```
min-width:100px;
```

Here is fiddel **http://jsfiddle.net/9Sha7/8/**

Comment: Sir,The output I am expecting is like the alphabet 'L', so I need to set this max-width, or can you suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

take out the padding

```
.grandParant{
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
min-width:100px;
max-width:120px;    
height:150px;
position:relative;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
border-right: 1px solid #000000;
background:#cccccc;
font-size:11px;
cursor:pointer;    
}
.parant1{
    width:auto;
margin-bottom:22px;

text-align:center;
    background:blue;
}
.parant2{

text-align:left;
width:auto;
background:#f3f3f3;
}

.child{
     width:100%;
position:static;
background:green;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Its not what I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of all the `width` attributes and the `max-width`, then it should be fine according to your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/9Sha7/13/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-width` from your `.grandParent` class and give `white-space:nowrap;` to your `.child` class.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Sha7/21/)**